# How can Minoru go to Nagoya for days?

Tags: akb49

Around chapter 100 to 130 of the manga,

> Yoshinaga Hiroko and Urakawa Minori went to Nagoya to attend SKE48 as a part of their role as the international member.

While the school knows that Yoshinaga is a member of AKB48 and thus there would be no problem with her skipping class for days, they didn't know that Urakawa Minoru is also a member.

Since going back and forth from Nagoya to Tokyo everyday is certainly not possible, considering that

> Minoru was performing 3 times a day in the park.

How did Minoru was able to skip class for a whole month without causing the school to contact his parents?

Comment: the shinkansen from Nagoya to Tokyo is ~2 and a half hours, which would be a hellish commute - perhaps not impossible though

Comment: Does it run early in the morning? Considering that school will start @around 8. Also they surely have practice lessons too albeit not told in the story. And Minori missing everyday for a whole month at exactly the same time span would rise suspicions, don't you think?

Comment: most trains start at around~6, so it'd be there for 8:40ish.  (I haven't seen the anime)